# Flutter: Cómo mover un nodo en Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter

Tengo un nodo dentro de la base de datos Firebase que tiene múltiples hijos y estos a su vez otros hijos. Quiero trasladar todo el nodo de una localización a otra dentro de la base, para lo cual hice una función con el API REST de Firebase. Ahora estoy migrando al SDK de Firebase que tiene más funcionalidades, pero no encuentro cómo hacer esto de una forma simple.

La función que tengo y que venía trabaja correctamente es la siguiente:

```
  Future<bool> moverLoteActual() async {
    
    //LEER DESDE EL PATH DE ORIGEN
    final urlLoteActual = '$_PATH_ORIGEN.../loteActual.json?auth=${_prefs.token}';

    final resp = await http.get(urlLoteActual);
    //TODO: Aquí creo que debiera prever si hay un error, no sé como hacerlo....

    //COPIAR EN EL PATH DE DESTINO
    final urlLotesCerrados = '$PATH_DESTINO.../lotesCerrados.json?auth=${_prefs.token}';

    final resp2 = await http.post(urlLotesCerrados, body: resp.body); 
    final decodedData2 = json.decode(resp2.body);
    print(decodedData2);

    //BORRAR EL CHILD DEL ORIGEN
    final resp3 = await http.delete(urlLoteActual);
    print(json.decode(resp3.body));

    return true;

  }
```

Tal vez con el SDK pueda implementarse de manera no tan secuencial como con el API. Saben si hay alguna forma?

**ACTUALIZACION**

En la consola de Firebase aparecen 4 tipos de operaciones: Modificado, Añadido, Eliminado y **Movido**. Cómo se ejecuta en Flutter SDK ese último tipo de operación?

[image: Tipos de operaciones en Firebase]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hallar la solución, es importante conocer las características del elemento de tipo DataSnapshot que se obtiene al hacer una consulta. Este elemento es del tipo Map<dynamic, dynamic>, entonces, lo primero que debe hacer la función es Leer desde el Path de Origen de la siguiente forma:

```
 //LEER DESDE EL PATH DE ORIGEN
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> _map = new Map<dynamic, dynamic>();
  Query resp = db.child('--PATH ORIGEN--/loteActual');  

  final snapshot = await resp.once();
  _map = snapshot.value;
```

Después, es importante entender que para escribir un mapa en Firebase, los keys son Strings y los valores son de cualquier tipo. Esto es, el mapa debe ser del tipo Map<String, dynamic>. El código para escribir en el destino es el siguiente:

```
    //COPIAR EN EL PATH DE DESTINO
  db.child('--PATH DESTINO--/lotesCerrados')
    .push().update(Map<String, dynamic>.from(_map));
```

Por último, se debe borrar el nodo origen, lo cual se hace con el comando estándar del SDK de Flutter para Firebase...

```
    //BORRAR EL CHILD DEL ORIGEN
  db.child('--PATH ORIGEN--/loteActual').remove();
```

Nótese que db, se refiere a la referencia de la instancia de Firebase (db = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference())

El código completo de la función es el siguiente:

```
Future<bool> moverLoteActual() async {
        
  //LEER DESDE EL PATH DE ORIGEN
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> _map = new Map<dynamic, dynamic>();
  Query resp = db.child('--PATH ORIGEN--/loteActual');  
    
  final snapshot = await resp.once();
  _map = snapshot.value;

  //COPIAR EN EL PATH DE DESTINO
  db.child('--PATH DESTINO--/lotesCerrados')
    .push().update(Map<String, dynamic>.from(_map));

  //BORRAR EL CHILD DEL ORIGEN
  db.child('--PATH ORIGEN--/loteActual').remove();

  return true;
}
```

Espero sea de utilidad