# Flutter: Cómo obtener la lista de Objetos asociada a una lista de IDs en Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter

Tengo una lista de IDs (key values) llamada _listaIdEmpresas. Quiero hacer una consulta simple de las empresas a las que corresponden dichos IDs y no logro hacerlo.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
  Future<List<EmpresaDatosModel>> cargarEmpresaDatosListado(List<String> listaIdEmpresas) async {

  final List<EmpresaDatosModel> listaEmpresas = new List(); 

  Query resp = db.child('empresas')
              .orderByKey().equalTo(listaIdEmpresas); // EN ESTA LINEA ME APARECE EL ASSERTION ERROR

  final snapshot = await resp.once();

      if (snapshot.value == null) return [];
      if (snapshot.value['error'] != null) return []; 

      snapshot.value.forEach((id, item){
        final temp = EmpresaDatosModel.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic>.from(item['datos']));
        temp.idEmpresa = id;

        listaEmpresas.add(temp);
      });
      print('Lista Empresasssssss ${listaEmpresas.length}');
      return listaEmpresas;
}
```

Cuando intento poner la lista como un parámetro **equalTo** dentro de la consulta me aparece el siguiente error:

> Exception has occurred.
> _AssertionError ('package:firebase_database/src/query.dart': Failed assertion: line 139 pos 12: 'value is String ||
> value is bool ||
> value is double ||
> value is int ||
> value == null': is not true.)

Supongo este error, es debido a que **equalTo** está esperando un String y no una lista, pero lo que necesito es precisamente traer el resultado de las Empresas que están en la lista.

Creo que una opción sería hacer una consulta para cada Id, pero es muy ineficiente, pudiendo simplemente traer el resultado de las Empresas asociadas a la Lista de Ids.

Alguien sabe cómo puedo resolverlo?

Comment: Ese es el problema de una base de datos NOSQL, tienes que ver la forma como estructurarla para filtrar datos.

Comment: Significa que no es una consulta posible? Hay que hacer un workaround?

Comment: @diegoveloper sabes si hay alguna forma simple de mover programáticamente un nodo con sus childs de una localización a otra? Hice la pregunta en [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/380038/flutter-c%c3%b3mo-mover-un-nodo-en-firebase)

Comment: tienes que recorrer el nodo y sus subcolumnas una por una e insertarlas en otro nodo, luego eliminar las subcolumnas y luego el nodo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hay una forma de consultar directamente en Firebase los Objetos asociados con el ID de una lista. Dado lo anterior, la forma más eficiente de lograrlo para no hacer muchas lecturas (consume tiempo y recursos) es:

1. Leer todos los objetos y almacenarlos en una lista (p.e. `List<EmpresaDatosModel> _listaEmpresasFull`)
2. Crear una lista que contiene únicamente los objetos asociados con el ID de la siguiente forma:

   ```
    final List<EmpresaDatosModel> _listaEmpresas = 
     _listaEmpresasFull.where((empresa) => _listaIdEmpresas.contains(empresa.idEmpresa)).toList();
   ```